# Is it possible to solve $k = \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, lambert-w

Is it possible to solve $k = \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ for $x$? My suspicion after a fruitless hour of manipulation is that it is not.

Comment: Do you know [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: Depends what exactly you mean by "solve".  Every continuous piecewise monotonic function has inverse function(s), but some are more easily described than others.

Comment: Consult vadim's link, and try $y = -\ln(x)$ in your equation.

Comment: the range of $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ is $(-\infty, 0) \cup (e , \infty)$

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved with the Lambert W function.

First let $y=\frac1x$. 
Then let $z=\ln(y)$, and use the Lambert W function. Then substitute back.

\begin{align*} k &= \frac{x}{\ln x} \\  k &= \frac{\frac1y}{\ln \frac1y} \\  k &= \frac{1}{y\ln \frac1y} \\ k &= -\frac{1}{y\ln y} \\ -\tfrac{1}k &= y\ln y 
\\ -\tfrac{1}k &= e^zz
\\ W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right) &= z
\\ W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right) &= \ln(y)
\\ e^{W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)} &= y
\\ e^{W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)} &= \tfrac1x
\\ e^{-W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)} &= x
\end{align*}

Hence $x= e^{-W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)} $.

Note that the Lambert W function is only defined for $x\geq-\tfrac{1}e$. Therefore we need $k>e$ or $k<0$. Otherwise there is no solution.

When $k>e$, we need to consider both branches of W. Then $x= e^{-W_0\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)} \vee e^{-W_{-1}\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)}$.

Note that we need the Lambert W function. If $e^{-W\left(-\tfrac{1}k\right)}$ could be written with just elementary functions, then $W(x)$ can be written using just elementary functions. But it has been proven that it can't.

Comment: Worth noting also that this equation *cannot* be solved exactly by a system which does not include Lambert-W. The fact that elementary functions (powers, roots, log, exp, sums, products and compositions) do not include Lambert-W is a very difficult result of modern mathematics, using tools from a field called *differential Galois theory*.

Comment: @EricStucky I included it.

Comment: Right, but you're missing a solution when $k\ge e$.

Comment: @egreg Yes, there are two branches of W. I included the other branch.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=x-k\ln x$, defined for $x>0$. We have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $k>0$}\\[4px]
-\infty & \text{if $k<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

We already see that a solution for $f(x)=0$ (which is the same as your equation) exists when $k<0$, but this is not sufficient.

Consider the derivative
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{k}{x}=\frac{x-k}{x}
$$

### Case $k<0$

If $k<0$, the derivative is positive everywhere, so the function is increasing and we get a single solution.

### Case $k=0$

There is no solution, because this would imply $x=0$, but the equation makes no sense for $x\le0$.

### Case $k>0$

So let $k>0$. We see that the function has a minimum at $k$, with
$$
f(k)=k(1-\ln k)
$$
The number of solutions then depends on whether $1-\ln k$ is positive (no solution), zero (one solution) or negative (two solutions). Clearly, $1-\ln k>0$ if and only if $0<k<e$.

### Summary

- no solution if $0<k<e$;
- one solution if $k=e$ or $k<0$
- two solutions if $k>e$.

With numerical methods you can approximate the solutions to the required accuracy.

Comment: For your information: I added some information regarding the negative cases to your summary at the end. Feel free to revert the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks, I reformatted again for better clarity.